# Lightning experience bug with empty (custom) object's list to order

Tags: custom-object, lightning-experience, bug, view, issue

I open this ticket to send my last issue with Lightning Experience, hope this will be read by developers themselves to improve it.

This happens when I try to order an empty list of records from one of my object (I know, useless to do but still possible).

Default state of the object:

[image]

When clicking on "Commission Name" to order them, those stacktraces appear.

```
 ID: 9b613cce-088c-455e-abb5-47767801021f)

Uncaught Error in $A.getCallback() [Cannot read property 'setParams' of null]
throws at https://sandorg--dev.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/OyuC6ZzcIcLPCr7b1ivFew/aura_proddebug.js:17470:9
    at Object.fireKeyboardModeExitEvent (https://sandorg--dev.lightning.force.com/l/%7B%22mode%22%3A%22PRODDEBUG%22%2C%22app%22%3A%22one%3Aone%22%2C%22fwuid%22%3A%22OyuC6ZzcIcLPCr7b1ivFew%22%2C%22loaded%22%3A%7B%22APPLICATION%40markup%3A%2F%2Fone%3Aone%22%3A%22NXLES3ilEm96ISutsWy_8w%22%7D%2C%22requestedLocales%22%3A%5B%22en_GB%22%2C%22en%22%2C%22fr%22%5D%2C%22ls%22%3A%22NN%22%7D/app.js:91089:38)
    at KeyboardNavManager.exitKeyboardMode (https://sandorg--dev.lightning.force.com/l/%7B%22mode%22%3A%22PRODDEBUG%22%2C%22app%22%3A%22one%3Aone%22%2C%22fwuid%22%3A%22OyuC6ZzcIcLPCr7b1ivFew%22%2C%22loaded%22%3A%7B%22APPLICATION%40markup%3A%2F%2Fone%3Aone%22%3A%22NXLES3ilEm96ISutsWy_8w%22%7D%2C%22requestedLocales%22%3A%5B%22en_GB%22%2C%22en%22%2C%22fr%22%5D%2C%22ls%22%3A%22NN%22%7D/app.js:210938:24)
    at KeyboardNavManager.<anonymous> (https://sandorg--dev.lightning.force.com/l/%7B%22mode%22%3A%22PRODDEBUG%22%2C%22app%22%3A%22one%3Aone%22%2C%22fwuid%22%3A%22OyuC6ZzcIcLPCr7b1ivFew%22%2C%22loaded%22%3A%7B%22APPLICATION%40markup%3A%2F%2Fone%3Aone%22%3A%22NXLES3ilEm96ISutsWy_8w%22%7D%2C%22requestedLocales%22%3A%5B%22en_GB%22%2C%22en%22%2C%22fr%22%5D%2C%22ls%22%3A%22NN%22%7D/app.js:211761:30)
    at https://sandorg--dev.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/OyuC6ZzcIcLPCr7b1ivFew/aura_proddebug.js:17460:23



ID: 4cb7893d-2979-4b42-87f5-02c8c8b2a482)

Access Check Failed! Component.getEvent():'onKeyboardModeExit' of component 'markup://ui:inlineEditGrid {361:0} {grid}' is not visible to 'InvalidComponent markup://aura:html {38:648;a}'.
    at Logger.error (https://sandorg--dev.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/OyuC6ZzcIcLPCr7b1ivFew/aura_proddebug.js:3752:9)
    at AuraInstance.error (https://sandorg--dev.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/OyuC6ZzcIcLPCr7b1ivFew/aura_proddebug.js:17373:17)
    at componentConstructor.Component.$getEvent$ (https://sandorg--dev.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/OyuC6ZzcIcLPCr7b1ivFew/aura_proddebug.js:5874:12)
    at Object.fireKeyboardModeExitEvent (https://sandorg--dev.lightning.force.com/l/%7B%22mode%22%3A%22PRODDEBUG%22%2C%22app%22%3A%22one%3Aone%22%2C%22fwuid%22%3A%22OyuC6ZzcIcLPCr7b1ivFew%22%2C%22loaded%22%3A%7B%22APPLICATION%40markup%3A%2F%2Fone%3Aone%22%3A%22NXLES3ilEm96ISutsWy_8w%22%7D%2C%22requestedLocales%22%3A%5B%22en_GB%22%2C%22en%22%2C%22fr%22%5D%2C%22ls%22%3A%22NN%22%7D/app.js:91089:8)
    at KeyboardNavManager.exitKeyboardMode (https://sandorg--dev.lightning.force.com/l/%7B%22mode%22%3A%22PRODDEBUG%22%2C%22app%22%3A%22one%3Aone%22%2C%22fwuid%22%3A%22OyuC6ZzcIcLPCr7b1ivFew%22%2C%22loaded%22%3A%7B%22APPLICATION%40markup%3A%2F%2Fone%3Aone%22%3A%22NXLES3ilEm96ISutsWy_8w%22%7D%2C%22requestedLocales%22%3A%5B%22en_GB%22%2C%22en%22%2C%22fr%22%5D%2C%22ls%22%3A%22NN%22%7D/app.js:210938:24)
    at KeyboardNavManager.<anonymous> (https://sandorg--dev.lightning.force.com/l/%7B%22mode%22%3A%22PRODDEBUG%22%2C%22app%22%3A%22one%3Aone%22%2C%22fwuid%22%3A%22OyuC6ZzcIcLPCr7b1ivFew%22%2C%22loaded%22%3A%7B%22APPLICATION%40markup%3A%2F%2Fone%3Aone%22%3A%22NXLES3ilEm96ISutsWy_8w%22%7D%2C%22requestedLocales%22%3A%5B%22en_GB%22%2C%22en%22%2C%22fr%22%5D%2C%22ls%22%3A%22NN%22%7D/app.js:211761:30)
    at https://sandorg--dev.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/OyuC6ZzcIcLPCr7b1ivFew/aura_proddebug.js:17460:23



 ID: 0aaa9ea2-d62f-42dc-8389-b72f8fdb6916)

Access Check Failed! AttributeSet.set(): 'inKeyboardMode' of component 'markup://ui:inlineEditGrid {361:0} {grid}' is not visible to 'InvalidComponent markup://aura:html {38:648;a}'.
    at Logger.error (https://sandorg--dev.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/OyuC6ZzcIcLPCr7b1ivFew/aura_proddebug.js:3752:9)
    at AuraInstance.error (https://sandorg--dev.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/OyuC6ZzcIcLPCr7b1ivFew/aura_proddebug.js:17373:17)
    at AttributeSet.set (https://sandorg--dev.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/OyuC6ZzcIcLPCr7b1ivFew/aura_proddebug.js:8748:12)
    at componentConstructor.Component.set (https://sandorg--dev.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/OyuC6ZzcIcLPCr7b1ivFew/aura_proddebug.js:5747:35)
    at KeyboardNavManager.exitKeyboardMode (https://sandorg--dev.lightning.force.com/l/%7B%22mode%22%3A%22PRODDEBUG%22%2C%22app%22%3A%22one%3Aone%22%2C%22fwuid%22%3A%22OyuC6ZzcIcLPCr7b1ivFew%22%2C%22loaded%22%3A%7B%22APPLICATION%40markup%3A%2F%2Fone%3Aone%22%3A%22NXLES3ilEm96ISutsWy_8w%22%7D%2C%22requestedLocales%22%3A%5B%22en_GB%22%2C%22en%22%2C%22fr%22%5D%2C%22ls%22%3A%22NN%22%7D/app.js:210937:17)
    at KeyboardNavManager.<anonymous> (https://sandorg--dev.lightning.force.com/l/%7B%22mode%22%3A%22PRODDEBUG%22%2C%22app%22%3A%22one%3Aone%22%2C%22fwuid%22%3A%22OyuC6ZzcIcLPCr7b1ivFew%22%2C%22loaded%22%3A%7B%22APPLICATION%40markup%3A%2F%2Fone%3Aone%22%3A%22NXLES3ilEm96ISutsWy_8w%22%7D%2C%22requestedLocales%22%3A%5B%22en_GB%22%2C%22en%22%2C%22fr%22%5D%2C%22ls%22%3A%22NN%22%7D/app.js:211761:30)
    at https://sandorg--dev.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/OyuC6ZzcIcLPCr7b1ivFew/aura_proddebug.js:17460:23




ID: 8ec43780-3344-4611-aca5-4868c08542a4)

Access Check Failed! AttributeSet.get(): attribute 'inKeyboardMode' of component 'markup://ui:inlineEditGrid {361:0} {grid}' is not visible to 'InvalidComponent markup://aura:html {38:648;a}'.
    at Logger.error (https://sandorg--dev.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/OyuC6ZzcIcLPCr7b1ivFew/aura_proddebug.js:3752:9)
    at AuraInstance.error (https://sandorg--dev.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/OyuC6ZzcIcLPCr7b1ivFew/aura_proddebug.js:17373:17)
    at AttributeSet.get (https://sandorg--dev.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/OyuC6ZzcIcLPCr7b1ivFew/aura_proddebug.js:8679:12)
    at componentConstructor.Component.set (https://sandorg--dev.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/OyuC6ZzcIcLPCr7b1ivFew/aura_proddebug.js:5746:32)
    at KeyboardNavManager.exitKeyboardMode (https://sandorg--dev.lightning.force.com/l/%7B%22mode%22%3A%22PRODDEBUG%22%2C%22app%22%3A%22one%3Aone%22%2C%22fwuid%22%3A%22OyuC6ZzcIcLPCr7b1ivFew%22%2C%22loaded%22%3A%7B%22APPLICATION%40markup%3A%2F%2Fone%3Aone%22%3A%22NXLES3ilEm96ISutsWy_8w%22%7D%2C%22requestedLocales%22%3A%5B%22en_GB%22%2C%22en%22%2C%22fr%22%5D%2C%22ls%22%3A%22NN%22%7D/app.js:210937:17)
    at KeyboardNavManager.<anonymous> (https://sandorg--dev.lightning.force.com/l/%7B%22mode%22%3A%22PRODDEBUG%22%2C%22app%22%3A%22one%3Aone%22%2C%22fwuid%22%3A%22OyuC6ZzcIcLPCr7b1ivFew%22%2C%22loaded%22%3A%7B%22APPLICATION%40markup%3A%2F%2Fone%3Aone%22%3A%22NXLES3ilEm96ISutsWy_8w%22%7D%2C%22requestedLocales%22%3A%5B%22en_GB%22%2C%22en%22%2C%22fr%22%5D%2C%22ls%22%3A%22NN%22%7D/app.js:211761:30)
    at https://sandorg--dev.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/OyuC6ZzcIcLPCr7b1ivFew/aura_proddebug.js:17460:23
```

Thanks in advance by the Cloudrebelz' team :)

Comment: You should report this to Salesforce support. The purpose of this community is to support with customisation, rather than bug reports, especially on standard functionality.